# Removing brackets from Database name in mssql

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to connect python to mssql database and I want the program to list all databases available in mssql, but the output brings all the databases enclosed in brackets.

```
db_connection = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', database='', 
                               server='servername', Trusted_Connection='yes')
db_cursor = sce.cursor()    
db_cursor.execute('select name from sys.databases')
table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
print(df)
```

this  is the current output:

```
           0
0     [master]
1     [tempdb]
2      [model]
3       [msdb]
4  [StudiesDB]
5    [Studies]
6      [study]
7       [Test]
```

Any idea on how I can display the databases without brackets?

Comment: Without running the code, I am pretty sure that he `table_rows` list contains tuples of singletons, which should be displayed with brackets. You can extract the table names with `table_names = [r[0] for r in table_rows]`.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE wow! This actually did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @LaurentLAPORTE .

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the []

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0 : ['[Master]', '[MSDB]']
})
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x : x.replace('[', '')).apply(lambda x : x.replace(']',''))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(r'^\[|\]$', '')
```